# React JS - How to prevent component continuing to display when state changed

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have the following situation. My main component contains a component Word, with:

```js
<Word onClick={i => this.handleClick(i)} />
```

`handleClick()` calls a function `async getWord()` which `await` for some JSON and setting a variable **condition** on state via, `this.setState({ winCondition: data });`.

`winCondition` is initialized to **False**

In my main component, below the **Word component**, there is another component `WinLayout`:

```js
<WinLayout winCondition={this.state.winCondition} />

// With the class for WinLayout being

class WinLayout extends Component {
    render() {
      if (this.props.winCondition === true) { return some layout}
      if (this.props.winCondition === false) {return some other layout} 

//...
```

The idea is that Word tests if a condition is met on each click via by calling the `getWord` function, which setting the **condition** on state. The `async` attempts to set `winCondition` to true, but the initial render of the main component hasn't yet completed, so the condition variable isn't yet set to the new value. Therefore, `WinLayout` will render the `=== false` branch once. Once rendered, the main component receives the state update and re-renders, this time on the right branch `winCondition === true`. The problem is that these two branches result in different visual appearance (colors, texts), so there is a slight unpleasant `flicker` between the `false` and the **true** states.

Any suggestions how I can force the main component to not do this, and immediately re-render when the state has been set to **true**? Thank you.

I tried `this.forceUpdate` in the `async` function after setting `winCondition`, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You can set the loading state to true when `handleClick` is called, and set it to false once the `async` function `getWord()`  resolves

Comment: You can set that state as Mr.Victor Mog, wrote  `{winCondition ? <WinLayout1 /> : <WinLayout2 />}`, If we're understanding correctly.

Comment: There is no "loading" state, I just want to set that variable winCondition in state, and draw the WinLayout based on whether it was true or false. I don't get what the winCondition? would do, the component would still continue its display after this.SetState (branch "false"), and re-render once done (branch "true", since now the state has been set to true).

Answer (score 1):

If you understand correctly, then you can display the element `WinLayout` by an external condition: `{winCondition ? <WinLayout1 /> : <WinLayout2 />}`

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was that I was using a boolean for 3 different values essentially - undefined, true and false. When undefined, I wanted a generic behavior, while on true and false I wanted specific changes in display (color). But initializing the state variable with "false" meant it would display that "false" state for a brief moment before switching to the "true" state. Instead, I wrote "if state.winCondition === undefined" and placed the generic layout here, whereas when "true" or "false" it goes to specific, different branches. Thanks all for the ideas.